# Google Map (api v3) doesn't show 1 out of every 20 or 30 times on mobile ios with the PhoneGap framework

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, google-maps-api-3

It shows a blank screen every once in a while.

I wanted to use MapKit, but the plugin for PhoneGap is extremely out of date and does not work.  SO I am forced to use Google Maps Api (v3).  It works great, except every once in a while the map just doesn't load.  What could be causing this?  Is there a way to detect that the map didn't load and then retry?

Thank you

Comment: when a map only shows a gray color this usually is forced by missing/wrong parameters . Simply reloading the map would end in an infinite loop when you don't fix the issue.

Comment: @Dr.Molle So do you think it's caused by the user's location parameters not being ready? and then loading the map with null long/lat?  I don't think this is the case, but I will test it out.  Maybe I will keep looping until there is a location found and then load the map.